# Fit Bounds for Multiple Polygons google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygons

I'm trying to extend the map boundaries for several polygons, but it seems it is only extending the boundaries for the last polygon in the loop. Any suggestions for where I am going wrong?

```
 function FitBounds(){
    for (var i=0; i < shapes2.length; i++){
        var paths = shapes2[i].getPaths();
        var bounds= new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        paths.forEach(function(path){
           var ar = path.getArray();
           for(var i=0, l = ar.length; i <l; i++){
              bounds.extend(ar[i]);
           }
        })
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds)
 }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create the bounds outside of the loop.

```
function FitBounds(){
    var bounds= new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i=0; i < shapes2.length; i++){
        var paths = shapes2[i].getPaths();
        paths.forEach(function(path){
           var ar = path.getArray();
           for(var i=0, l = ar.length; i <l; i++){
              bounds.extend(ar[i]);
           }
        })
    }
    map.fitBounds(bounds)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI for other people getting here there are helper methods by the google maps library making it easier to get the bounds of a collection of shapes:

```
function FitBounds(){
    var bounds = shapes2.reduce((boundsAccumulator, shape) => 
      boundsAccumulator.union(shape.getBounds()), new google.maps.LatLngBounds())
    
    map.fitBounds(bounds)
 }
```

or if you're not a fan of reduce

```
function FitBounds(){
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds()
    
    shapes2.forEach(shape) => bounds.union(shape.getBounds()))
    
    map.fitBounds(bounds)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the Polygon method [getPaths()](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#Polygon.getPaths) to achieve the same in a simplified form.

```js
    const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    polygonList.forEach((polygon) => {
      polygon.getPaths().forEach((path) => {
        path.forEach((point) => {
          bounds.extend(point);
        });
      });
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
```